# EPPlus date format not changing correctly

Tags: .net, excel, epplus

I am creating EXCEL with EPPlus, and need to change the format of Date as per the format passed (dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy etc.)

```
If (schedulestart > -1) Then sheet.Column(schedulestart).Style.Numberformat.Format = fileDownload.DateFormat

 If (schedulefinish > -1) Then sheet.Column(schedulefinish).Style.Numberformat.Format = fileDownload.DateFormat

If (actualstart > -1) Then sheet.Column(actualstart).Style.Numberformat.Format = fileDownload.DateFormat
```

The issue is: with above code, it changes the format of first two columns but not of thirds. and if I remove third and only change the format of two columns it changes the first column and does not change for second.

[image]

I debug and it shows correct format during debug but changes for the last column afterwords.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, Got it. index for EPPlus starts from index 1 instead of index 0. makes sense now.